# DB::getQueryLog() not printing groupby

Tags: laravel

I have this query to be printed in normal SQL query:

```
Brand::get()->groupBy('name');
print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
```

but it is displaying only  `select * from brands` ignoring groupBy. Why is it ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're grouping after executing the query. The correct way to see your desired result:

```
Brand::groupBy('name')->get();
print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
```

What you're doing is executing the [groupBy on a Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-groupby). This is working also but it's laravel that is grouping and not your database. That's why you won't see the groupBy command in the SQL query.

---

Comment: but these are two different sql queries.

Comment: @Steve what do you mean? I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: aren't `->get()->groupBy('name');` and `groupBy('name')->get()` different?

Comment: @Steve I've edited my answer and added an explanation.

Comment: oh well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
Brand::groupBy('name')->toSql();
```

This will print sql query.